Extend existing Hibernate Entity as Android Room Entity with Kotlin Serialization annotation
I need to utilize an existing database structure which has Entity classes compatible with JPA (Jakarta Persistence API) for use in Spring Boot via the Hibernate ORM.  I want to basically copy this database structure as an Android Room database and also use the Kotlin serialization plugin / library.  The original database library cannot use any Android dependencies.  The problem I'm confronted with is PrimaryKey annotations in the Android Room database.  I cannot find a way to designate the fields as primary keys from the original Entity.  Example follows...
CustomerEntity.kt - JPA Entity class compatible with Spring Hibernate
@Serializable
@Entity
@Table(
    name = CustomerEntity.Constants.TABLE_NAME,
    indexes = [Index(name = "IX_Customer_CustomerName", columnList = "CustomerName")]
)
open class CustomerEntity(
    @Id
    @Column(name = Constants.COLUMN_ID_NAME, nullable = false, length = 15)
    open var id: String = "",

    @Column(name = Constants.COLUMN_CUSTOMERNAME_NAME, length = 40)
    var customerName: String = "",
) {
    object Constants {
        const val TABLE_NAME: String = "Customer"
        const val COLUMN_ID_NAME: String = "CustomerID"
        const val COLUMN_CUSTOMERNAME_NAME: String = "CustomerName"
    }
}

CustomerAndroid.kt - attempted to subclass JPA Entity class
@Serializable
@Entity(tableName = CustomerSchema.TABLE_NAME)
class CustomerAndroid() : CustomerEntity() {
    constructor(
        customerID: String,
        customerName: String = ""
    ) : this() {
        this.id = customerID
        this.customerName = customerName
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    override var id: String = ""
}

Attempting to use override produces a problem with kotlinx.serialization:
Serializable class has duplicate serial name of property 'id', either in the class itself or its supertypes

I'm trying to find a way to attach the annotation to the primary key field in Android Room, but I'm running into a lot of headaches with getting these frameworks and libraries to play nicely with each other.
